# Buttons in new GWT App

Tags: java, gwt

I just started with GWT. I made the tutorial given [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted?hl=bg-BG) . But when I created new project and added two buttons in a horizontal panel and then in the RootPanel it displayed me just the header I've made in the HTML file. Can you tell me what could be the reason? 
Here is the Java class, the HTML and the XML : 
Java Class:

```
    package org.elsys.salvation.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;


public class Salvation implements EntryPoint {

    private Button newData = new Button("New");
    private Button existingData = new Button("Existing");
    private HorizontalPanel mainHorizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    private Label lastUpdatedLabel = new Label();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        mainHorizontalPanel.add(newData);
        mainHorizontalPanel.add(existingData);
        mainHorizontalPanel.add(lastUpdatedLabel);

        RootPanel.get("Salvation").add(mainHorizontalPanel);
    }

}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Salvation.css">
        <title>Diploma Defences Organiser</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="stockwatcher/stockwatcher.nocache.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Diploma Defences Organiser</h1>
        <div id="Salvation"></div>
        <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
        <noscript>
            <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
            Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
            in order for this application to display correctly.
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='Salvation'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='org.elsys.salvation.client.Salvation'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

Comment: how did you start the project. Are you using eclipse as you coding enviroment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line whether it is correct or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="stockwatcher/stockwatcher.nocache.js"></script>
```

I think you should have something like: `Salvation/Salvation.nocache.js` as source of script tag.

Comment: @malkoto1 check that .nocache.js file is accessible from that URL, it should work if nocache.js file is available from that page....

Answer (score 0):

In your browser of choice open up the developer console.  You should be able to track the web requests made.  Make sure your *nocache.js file is called and comes back ok (Status 200).

If that works ok nothing else obvious jumps out at me.  Maybe try not specifying the div you want to load to?

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(mainHorizontalPanel);
```

Comment: The javascript is being called but in the console appears the following error: Uncaught TypeError: " Cannot set property '__gwt_getProperty' of undefined " and it appers after that line of code:
" function B(){if(p&&q){var b=m.getElementById(O);var c=b.contentWindow;if(A()){c.__gwt_getProperty=function(a){return F(a)}}Salvation=null;c.gwtOnLoad(y,O,s,x);n&&n({moduleName:O,sessionId:o,subSystem:P,evtGroup:V,millis:(new Date).getTime(),type:W})}} "

Comment: That's the generated js that can be hard to debug visually.  Are you running from the tomcat server in eclipse or compiling then deploying?

Comment: I'm using the Developement mode of eclipse and just run it